# Testing the "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in unit testing using Rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I am new to rails and testing models. My model class is like this:

```
class Tester < Person
  has_one :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skill   
end
```

And I want to do test for "accepts_nested_attributes_for :skill" using rspec with out any other gem.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

There are convenient `shoulda` gem matchers for testing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but you mentioned that you don't want to use other gems. So, using Rspec only, the idea is to set `attributes` hash that would include required `Tester` attributes and nested hash called `skill_attributes` that would include required `Skill` attributes; then pass it into `create` method of `Tester`, and see if it changes the number of `Testers` and number of `Skills`. Something like that:

```
class Tester < Person
  has_one :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skill
  # lets say tester only has name required;
  # don't forget to  add :skill to attr_accessible
  attr_accessible :name, :skill
  .......................
 end
```

Your tests:

```
 # spec/models/tester_spec.rb
 ......
 describe "creating Tester with valid attributes and nested Skill attributes" do
   before(:each) do
     # let's say skill has languages and experience attributes required
     # you can also get attributes differently, e.g. factory
     @attrs = {name: "Tester Testov", skill_attributes: {languages: "Ruby, Python", experience: "3 years"}}
   end

   it "should change the number of Testers by 1" do
      lambda do
        Tester.create(@attrs)
      end.should change(Tester, :count).by(1)
   end

   it "should change the number of Skills by 1" do
      lambda do
        Tester.create(@attrs)
      end.should change(Skills, :count).by(1)
   end
 end
```

Hash syntax may be different. Also, if you have any uniqueness validations, make sure you are generating `@attrs` hash dynamically before every test.
Cheers, mate.